# Firefox Not Rendering Columns in Print View

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a `div` with 2 `divs` inside of it, each with a `ul` of content, so it looks like two columns in the view. I'm using `window.print` and css to print these out, Chrome and Safari work fine, but Firefox is turning the 2 columns into 1.

```html
  <div class="Sides">
    <div class="left side">
      <ul>
        <li class="List">
          <div>
            <div>
              <div class="circle">
                1
              </div>
              <select>
                <option disabled="disabled">
                  Select 
                </option>
                <option selected="selected" value="1">
                  1
                </option>
              </select> <label>Label</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form">
              <div class="A">
                <span >A</span><span></span>
              </div>
              <select >
                <option selected="selected" value="A" >
                  A
                </option>

                <option value="B" >
                  B
                </option>

                <option value="C">
                  C
                </option>
              </select><label>Select</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="List">
          <div>
            <div>
              <div class="circle">
                1
              </div>
              <select>
                <option disabled="disabled">
                  Select 
                </option>
                <option selected="selected" value="1">
                  1
                </option>
              </select> <label>Label</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form">
              <div class="A">
                <span >A</span><span></span>
              </div>
              <select >
                <option selected="selected" value="A" >
                  A
                </option>

                <option value="B" >
                  B
                </option>

                <option value="C">
                  C
                </option>
              </select><label>Select</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here it is on Chrome/Safari:

[image]

Here it is on Firefox:

[image]

I've tried `column-count`, `column-fill`, `float` (left/right for diff divs), `min-width: 0` / `min-height: 0`, and I can't seem to get the 2 columns to appear.

Anyone have any other suggestions for how to get this to work?

Comment: Start here: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone ever runs into this issue again I had to set the `@media print` to `min-width: 0px;` in order to get the columns to print out like they should. Then, to get them the width I needed I had to set a `width: 500px;` (or whatever width you need) to get them to print out like I needed them. Such a strange bug, but it's fixed now!

Comment: Would you happen to have a completed version of the css? I know this is literally 6 years later lol

Comment: @ScottUphus -- sorry no that was *many* jobs ago! I don't even do web anymore. Good luck!